# Error during GetToken task while installing Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

Hello I am trying to Install Sitecore Commerce. Install fails at the following. I have tried everything. Assign full permission to CSFndRuntime user for the identity.server certificate. anyone have seen this problem?

> Get Token From Sitecore.IdentityServer
>   VERBOSE: POST https://localhost:5050/connect/token with -1-byte payload
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
>   +                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   +                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:02
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   At C:\SitecoreInstaller\Sitecore.Commerce.2018.12-2.4.63\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.4.7\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:86
>   char:2
>   +     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -verbose -Skip CreateDefaul ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:06
>   Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS
>   secure channel.
>   At C:\SitecoreInstaller\Sitecore.Commerce.2018.12-2.4.63\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.4.7\Modules\InitializeCommerce\Initial
>   izeCommerce.psm1:73 char:17
>   + ... $response = Invoke-RestMethod $UrlIdentityServerGetToken -Method Post ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
>      eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: can you verify that SSL certificate for Identity Server exists in Trusted Root Certificate for your machine

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue initially while setting up Sitecore Commerce 9. Ensure your identity app pool user (for e.g. Server_Name\CSFndRuntimeUser) has been added & given permission to Identity Server client certificate (e.g. identity.server) under Certificate Manager (Certificates > Personal > Certificates). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below configuration at postman side:

- SSL Certificate verification should be Off at your postman setting

[image]

You can refer the below blog to setup you postman:

https://davehetal.wordpress.com/2018/11/05/_sitecore-xc-9-0-2-postman-setup/